# App Chooser with default selector

Tags: android, android-intent

I've written a small application which allows to load up an image from gallery by running these lines of code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getResources().getString(R.string.select_image)), 1);
```

Now my problem is that I've got to choose an application everytime again. I would like to be able to select the default application for this action.
For example I don't want always be asked which Gallery I would like to use, I would like to be able to select one standard gallery which will be used as default.

EDIT: I would like to have these[image] buttons at the dialog's button which allows the "always" or "just once" selection.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Bojan Kseneman I don't mean to pre-select a specific application! I would like the user to choose which application he want's to set as "default" or "ask always".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to be able to select the default application for this action.

If you get rid of `Intent.createChooser()`, and instead just call `startActivityForResult()` with your `Intent`, the user will have the option of setting a default choice for this `Intent` structure, if they have not done so already.